# Is there any option to delete the downloaded installer after auto update completion?

Tags: install4j

Is there any option to delete the downloaded files after auto update functionality completion ?

Answer (score 0):

As of 6.1.4, that is not an option in install4j. You would have to save them to a special directory and delete that at application startup.

Comment: I am using 6.1.4 version. Please share the option.

Comment: As I said, there is no currently no option to do that. I'm adding "as of 6.1.4" to qualify this statement for future readers.